# Operator controller could not delete correlated resources

Tags: kubernetes, operator-sdk

In Kubernetes and Operator-sdk, we can define CRD (Custom Resource Definition) and CR (Custom Resource). In my operator controller, when a CR is initialized, then I create a new Deployment and service.

When we delete a CR object, then the correlated resources (such as Deployment or service) will be deleted as well at the same time. I understand it should be done by `CR` or `CRD` finalizer, this is just my guess.

Now I hit an issue, during Operator testing, under `envTest` environment, when I delete a `CR`, its correlated resources (Deployment or service) have not been deleted.

I am confused. In `real k8s cluster`, the correlated resources (Deployment or service) can be deleted automatically when I delete a `CR`, under `envTest environment`, why it doesn't delete correlated resources?

Could anybody point out the reason.

Comment: A related issue on the controller-runtime's GitHub repo:
https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-runtime/issues/626

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deletion of orphaned resources is done by Kubernetes's [garbage collector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/garbage-collection/), which is implemented in [kubelet](https://v1-16.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/kubelet-garbage-collection/). When you test operator in `envTest` environment, garbage collection doesn't work because `kubelet` is missing in that environment(it only deploys API server and etcd).

Comment: Thanks @Grigoriy Mikhalkin, you are expert in this area.